# Why does one radar/spider plot had straight sides and another has curved edges, despite being created with the same data?

Tags: r, ggplot2, radar-chart, geom, spider-chart

I used the following geom_polygon code to create the radar plot below. In this figure, my four treatment (ES, EO, LO, LS) are at the four polygon corners, and my shapes are specific to 4 streams (Blue, Pink, Orange, Yellow). This code produced a four-sized polygon with straight edges. The same dataset is used to create both figures. Table here:

| Substrate | Phase | vf |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Cobble | ES | 3.6 |
| Pea Gravel | ES | 4.5 |
| Mix | ES | 2.1 |
| Sand | ES | 1.9 |
| Cobble | EO | 5.6 |
| Pea Gravel | EO | 6.9 |
| Mix | EO | 3.2 |
| Sand | EO | 2.9 |
| Cobble | LO | 5.9 |
| Pea Gravel | LO | 7.4 |
| Mix | LO | 3.4 |
| Sand | LO | 3.1 |
| Cobble | LS | 1.8 |
| Pea Gravel | LS | 2.3 |
| Mix | LS | 1.1 |
| Sand | LS | 1.0 |

```
ggplot(data=nh420,  aes(x=phase, y=vf, group=substrate, colour=substrate))+ #
  annotate("text", x=4, y=c(2,4,6,8,10), label=c(2,4,6,8,10), hjust=0.5, vjust=1)+
  geom_polygon(size = 1.5, alpha= 0)+
  scale_y_continuous()+
  scale_x_discrete()+
  scale_colour_manual(values= c("#c55a11", "#ab3378", "#4677aa", "#cbbb44"))+
  #scale_fill_manual(values= c("#CA885F", "#B66C98","#4677aa","#cbbb44"))+
  #scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0),limits=c(0,10),breaks=seq(0,10,3))+
  #ylab(expression(NH["4"]~""^"+"-N~V["f"]~(m~d^{"-1"})))+
  theme_minimal()+
  theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.title.y=element_blank(),
        #axis.title.y=element_text(size=12,color="black"),
        #axis.text.y=element_text(size=10,color="black"),
        #axis.text.x=element_text(size=12,color="black"),
        axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.text.y=element_blank())+
  theme(legend.position="none")+
  coord_polar(start = -9.5)
```

[image]

However, when I switch around the x variable and grouping to create the inverse figure, the sides of the polygon are now curved. Why the drastic change in shape? The code for the second image (gray and yellow lines) is below.

```
ggplot(data=nh420,  aes(x=substrate, y=vf, group=phase, colour=phase))+ #
  annotate("text", x=4, y=0:3, label=0:3, hjust=0.5, vjust=1)+
  geom_polygon(size = 1.5, alpha= 0)+
  scale_y_continuous()+
  scale_x_discrete()+
  scale_colour_manual(values= c("gray75", "yellow", "goldenrod", "gray35"))+
  #scale_fill_manual(values= c("#CA885F", "#B66C98","#4677aa","#cbbb44"))+
  #scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0),limits=c(0,10),breaks=seq(0,10,3))+
  #ylab(expression("Areal Uptake,"~italic(U)~(mg~N~m^{"-2"}~h^{"-1"})))+
  theme_minimal()+
  theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.title.y=element_blank(),
        #axis.title.y=element_text(size=12,color="black"),
        #axis.text.y=element_text(size=10,color="black"),
        #axis.text.x=element_text(size=12,color="black"),
        axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.text.y=element_blank())+
  theme(legend.position="none")+
  coord_polar(start = -9.5)
```

[image]

I do not understand why the shape changes. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I once had this problem but found a custom function/trick on [Erwan Le Pennec blog](http://www.cmap.polytechnique.fr/%7Elepennec/en/post/radar/radarandparallelplots/)

**Step 1:** Create a custom radar coordinate system:

```r
coord_radar <- function (theta = "x", start = - pi / 2, direction = 1) {
  theta <- match.arg(theta, c("x", "y"))
  r <- if (theta == "x") "y" else "x"
  ggproto(
    "CordRadar", CoordPolar, theta = theta, r = r, start = start,
    direction = sign(direction),
    is_linear = function(coord) TRUE)
}
```

**Step 2:** Add the function to the plot object

```r
ggplot(data=df,  aes(x=Substrate, y=vf, group = Phase, colour =Phase))+ 
  annotate("text", x=4, y=0:3, label=0:3, hjust=0.5, vjust=1)+
  geom_polygon(size = 1.5, alpha= 0)+
  scale_colour_manual(values= c("gray75", "yellow", "goldenrod", "gray35"))+
  scale_y_continuous()+
  scale_x_discrete()+
  theme_minimal()+
  coord_radar(start = -9.5) #NEW and Custom Coordinate System
```

**Step 3:** Optional, rearrange the levels to make it easier to read.

```r
df$Substrate <- factor(df$Substrate,
                       levels = c(
                         "Mix",
                         "Pea Gravel",
                         "Cobble",
                         "Sand"
                       ))
```

**Final Result**, hope it helps.

[image: radar-plot-custom]

Comment: Thank you @AntonioAlegría! This plot is more comparable to my others. Do you have any idea what the underlying cause of the issue is? I don't understand why the curved sides appeared for one ordination, but not the other.